# How to change background color of TextBox by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am trying to change background color of textbox by using javascript but my code is not working. I search SO but not find any suitable answer. Here is my code.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function abc() {
            var v = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
            v.setAttribute('BackColor', 'Red');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="abc()" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: How about v.style.backgroundColor="red"; ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to change the UI that is html, so you need to use javascript/css properties.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-extended-h2) there is a list of css attributes accessible by javascript.

Try with:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function abc() {
            var v = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
            v.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    </script>
```

Furthermore I have the Visual Studio 2010 and the Intellisense also show me the `style` attribute:

[image]

You are right jams, when I pretend to point to an `id` from a html generated by asp the intellisense doesn't works for the `style` attribute:

[image]

[image]

I think the Intellisense doesn't reach to this `id` because at the moment of you are writting this code, the html doesn't exists.

Comment: I check it in Visual Studio 2010, but when I type `v` dot then intellisense windows does not has `style` option.

Comment: @jams It's so weird my Visual Studio 2010 does show me the `style` option. I think could be the `"<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>"`, because when I write a `document.getElementById("existingId")` and the `existingId` are in the html aspx file does behaves like I said.

Comment: can you post a screen shot for verification. I am posting my.

Comment: I have posted my. please check it.

Comment: you are using `<p id="texID"` and I am using `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">`. When you will try `TextBox` you will not get `style` option. Check it and tell me.

Comment: I think that is why @vcsjones has recommended `Resharper 6`.

Comment: @jams I don't think so, but you can try with `Resharper 6` but that would mean that the tool previously would have to understand the HTML generated by ASP.

Answer (score 2):

`BackColor` does not exist on the client side. That's an ASP.NET server-side notion. Rather, you want to set it with CSS:

```
v.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';
```

[Here](http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/css2js.htm) is a reference of the names of CSS properties as they would appear in JavaScript.

Comment: yes it works. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and its intellisense windows does not show `style` for `v`. Can you explain it why?

Comment: @jams I guess that is not registered in 2008, but in Visual Studio 2010 does.

Comment: @jams Galled is right, 2008 has very limited support for JavaScript intellisense. If you really want it, add ins like Resharper 6 + add it in, better than VS 2010 does.